# (Docker) ZUUL: Load balancer does not have available server for client

Tags: spring-boot, docker, microservices, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul

I am trying to create an API Gateway (ZUUL) which discovers a service from (EUREKA) and forwards it a spring boot microservice. All these services are running in an independent docker container. However, whenever I try to access API Gateway for the spring boot microservice, I get the following exception:

```
c.netflix.config.ChainedDynamicProperty  : Flipping property: KUBEIO-WINES-SERVICE.ribbon.ActiveConnectionsLimit to use NEXT property: niws.loadbalancer.availabilityFilteringRule.activeConnectionsLimit = 2147483647
c.netflix.loadbalancer.BaseLoadBalancer  : Client: KUBEIO-WINES-SERVICE instantiated a LoadBalancer: DynamicServerListLoadBalancer:{NFLoadBalancer:name=KUBEIO-WINES-SERVICE,current list of Servers=[],Load balancer stats=Zone stats: {},Server stats: []}ServerList:null
c.n.l.DynamicServerListLoadBalancer      : Using serverListUpdater PollingServerListUpdater
c.n.l.DynamicServerListLoadBalancer      : DynamicServerListLoadBalancer for client KUBEIO-WINES-SERVICE initialized: DynamicServerListLoadBalancer:{NFLoadBalancer:name=KUBEIO-WINES-SERVICE,current list of Servers=[],Load balancer stats=Zone stats: {},Server stats: []}ServerList:com.netflix.loadbalancer.ConfigurationBasedServerList@49a79208
o.s.c.n.z.filters.post.SendErrorFilter   : Error during filtering
com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: Forwarding error
    ...
Caused by: com.netflix.client.ClientException: Load balancer does not have available server for client: KUBEIO-WINES-SERVICE
    ...
```

I see that the services are successfully registered when I access http://localhost:8761/eureka/apps.

```
<applications>
    <versions__delta>1</versions__delta>
    <apps__hashcode>UP_3_</apps__hashcode>
<application>
<name>KUBEIO-WINES-SERVICE</name>
    <instance>
        <instanceId>d1956d3eaecc:kubeio-wines-service:8080</instanceId>
        <hostName>192.168.128.7</hostName>
        <app>KUBEIO-WINES-SERVICE</app>
        <ipAddr>192.168.128.7</ipAddr>
        <status>UP</status>
        <overriddenstatus>UNKNOWN</overriddenstatus>
        <port enabled="true">8080</port>
        <securePort enabled="false">443</securePort>
        <countryId>1</countryId>
        <dataCenterInfo class="com.netflix.appinfo.InstanceInfo$DefaultDataCenterInfo">
            <name>MyOwn</name>
        </dataCenterInfo>
        <leaseInfo>
            <renewalIntervalInSecs>30</renewalIntervalInSecs>
            <durationInSecs>90</durationInSecs>
            <registrationTimestamp>1640842407796</registrationTimestamp>
            <lastRenewalTimestamp>1640876348536</lastRenewalTimestamp>
            <evictionTimestamp>0</evictionTimestamp>
            <serviceUpTimestamp>1640842407289</serviceUpTimestamp>
        </leaseInfo>
        <metadata>
            <management.port>8080</management.port>
        </metadata>
        <homePageUrl>http://192.168.128.7:8080/</homePageUrl>
        <statusPageUrl>http://192.168.128.7:8080/actuator/info</statusPageUrl>
        <healthCheckUrl>http://192.168.128.7:8080/actuator/health</healthCheckUrl>
        <vipAddress>kubeio-wines-service</vipAddress>
        <secureVipAddress>kubeio-wines-service</secureVipAddress>
        <isCoordinatingDiscoveryServer>false</isCoordinatingDiscoveryServer>
        <lastUpdatedTimestamp>1640842407796</lastUpdatedTimestamp>
        <lastDirtyTimestamp>1640842407218</lastDirtyTimestamp>
        <actionType>ADDED</actionType>
    </instance>
</application>
<application>...</application>
<application>...</application>
</applications>
```

Here are my configurations.

**API Gateway (ZUUL)**

```
## Eureka
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=true
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://kubeio-discovery:8761/eureka
eureka.instance.preferIpAddress=true

## Zuul
zuul.routes.kubeio-wines-service.path=/wineservice/**
zuul.routes.kubeio-wines-service.service-id=KUBEIO-WINES-SERVICE
zuul.routes.kubeio-wines-service.strip-prefix=false

ribbon.eureka.enabled=true
```

**Discovery Server (Eureka)**

```
spring.application.name=discovery-server
server.port=8761
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
eureka.instance.hostname=localhost
eureka.instance.prefer-ip-address=true
```

**Spring Boot Microservice**

```
## Eureka
spring.application.name=kubeio-wines-service
eureka.client.registerWithEureka=true
eureka.client.fetchRegistry=true
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://kubeio-discovery:8761/eureka
eureka.instance.hostname=kubeio-wines-service
eureka.instance.preferIpAddress=true
```

This is what I see on the Eureka Dashboard.

[image]

All the services are running inside a docker container. I do not know what I am doing wrong. Any idea how do I get this working?